# Jquery Change on Select only fires onces

Tags: jquery

I have a list that I would like to show a `<div>` element on change.
The issue is that the div only shows once, if I change the selection and go back to the one that suppose to shows the `<div>` it does not work.
Any ideas why?

```
$("#request_status").change(function () {
    if ($('#request_status').val() != '2') {
        $('#status_update_options').hide();

    } else {
        $('#status_update_options').show();
    };
});
```

Here is the HTML part:

```
<div class="form-group" id="status_update_options">
    <label  class="col-lg-3  control-label">Options</label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="checkbox-list">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox"  value="mark_as_resolution" name="mark_as_resolution" > Mark Note as resolution </label>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the select part

```
<select class="form-control m-bot15 " id="request_status" name="request_status">
    <option value="0">Completed</option>
    <option value="1">Active</option>                                                                      
</select>
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML, particularly `#request_status` and its values?

Comment: can you post code demo? (more code pls)

Comment: Works fine is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v8zja9L0/. Can you post a complete code example where it's not? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Just added the HTML part.

Comment: There's no `request_status` in the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar Just added that too. Thank you.

Comment: There's no option 2 in the select, so it will always go to the `hide()` action.

Comment: Your code works [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/47z2u8ek/), but as @Barmar told you, I added an option with value `2`

Comment: ... but note that @FaresM. added the `<option value="2">` the posted code lacks.

Comment: advice ... instead of $('#request_status').val() you can use $(this).val() in your case

Comment: True.The select options are propogated using PHP> I guess I didn't see that one. Thank you for highlighting that.